# Pass a php variable in a script

Tags: javascript, php

I have the function below, how can I add my php variables id and fn instead of escape(window.location.href) ?

```
$mRow = $this->row;
$wRow = $mRow->getInfo(); 
$id= $mRow->id;
$fn = $mRow->first_name;

<script language="javascript">
  function fbshareCurrentPage()
    {window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
     return false; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
 var id= <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>;
 var fn = <?php echo json_encode($fn); ?>;

 function fbshareCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+id+"/"+fn+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
 return false; }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the below file is php file.

```
$mRow = $this->row;
$wRow = $mRow->getInfo(); 
$id= $mRow->id;
$fn = $mRow->first_name;

<script language="javascript">
  var id = '$id'; // Now you can use id directly in javascript
  var fn = '$fn'; //// Now you can use fn directly in javascript
  function fbshareCurrentPage()
    {window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+id+"&fn="+fn+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
     return false; }
</script>
```

You can assign value to javascript varibales and use them in script the way you want.

Comment: thank you! It's still not working but not because of the variables i think.

Comment: You can check the value of varaible in dev console by adding break point.

Comment: the values are working its the part betwen "u=" and "&t" that is not working

Comment: Can you try to use window.id and window.fn once.

Comment: no because that is how I want my link to be:

u=www.abc.com/abc/valueofID/valueofFN...

Comment: he needs to `echo "<script>...</script>"` stuff doesn't he?

Comment: the problem in your cde is that you are assigning $id as a string. but it is a variable

Comment: I guess it should be in single quotes. Am I right ?

Comment: no, it is still using them as a string and not as variables

Answer (score 0):

```
$mRow = $this->row;
$wRow = $mRow->getInfo(); 
$id= $mRow->id;
$fn = $mRow->first_name;

<script language="javascript">
  function fbshareCurrentPage()
    {window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+<?php echo $id; ?>+"&fn="+<?php echo $fn; ?>+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
     return false; }
</script>
```

Comment: jsn_encode means your values were have some special character etc which were not allowed to use directly in the url.

Comment: I have numbers and letters. No special values but it's the only way that works

Comment: It is good your problem have been solved. Your original question was how to pass the id and func variable in the script. Regarding that answer is ok.